# Доработка кода массива

Tags: java, массивы

Вечер добрый, простите за тупость, в java меньше 3-х недель и немного не понимаю как добавить переменную в код, чтобы сортировка была именно на столько мест, сколько стоит в этой переменной.

Функционал кода должен быть сохранен, чтобы остаток при неравных массивах записывался с массива который больше и не создавались пустые поля при прохождении оператора, когда массив, который короче "закончится".

Например нужно подставить именно переменную g = 3 или любую другую цифру;

Код ниже:

```
public static char[] meschat(char[] a, char[] b, int g) {
    int per = 0,
    int len = a.length + b.length;
    char[] res = new char[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 2; i++) {
        if (a.length > i) {
            res[per++] = a[i];
        }
        if (b.length > i) {
            res[per++] = b[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот же у Вас объявление переменной per типа int и инициализация её значением 0 `int per = 0`. А вот, например, объявление и инициализация переменной g `int g = 3`. Можно ещё добавить ';' для полного счастья: `int g = 3;`.

Comment: О какой сортировке речь? Необходимо в массиве-результате отсортировать количество элементов равное g? Тогда не перемешивайте формирование массива и его сортировку. Уже после формирования массива создайте переменную и, используя цикл от 0 до данной переменной, отсортируйте этот массив.

Comment: @justcvd Уже решил проблему, спасибо за ответ, но вылезла другая проблема, а именно - при онлайн тесте, когда у каждого массива по одному полю - возвращает пустой массив, хотя массива два не пустых .. Или второй массив равен null, то вместо того чтобы вернуть массив со значением, он возвращает 0 не смотря на то, что прописано возвращать со значением.. Сижу вот и думаю как исправить

Comment: "из". "ИЗ" массива, черт возьми!

Comment: @Igor не злись, друг..в теме новый.. с опытом наберусь

Comment: @Str не представляю, как опыт в программировании может улучшить ваше знание русского языка.

Comment: 3 раза прочитал и не понял. о чем вообще идет речь. Что возвращается, что нет, что за сортировка и черт побери, да покажите же вы уже наконец, что там за мего онлайн тестер, да хоть скриншотом, что вы там делаете.... То один вопрос, сразу другой возникает, потом 3 из ниоткуда появляются, даже по смыслу разные =)) Объясняйте подробнее что необходимо сделать. Иначе, никто помогать не будет и будут агриться и минусовать.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Русский такой, потому-что я перевожу с немецкого, а что тяжело перевести так, чтобы поняли другие , то у меня выходит дословно.. Немцы не говорят "Из массива" , скорее скажут "доработка кода, который работает с массивом" или "код для массива".. В этом прикол .. У меня общение в реальной жизни половина немецкими - половина русскими словами.. такое у всех, кто долго живет не в среде языка (в нашем случае Русского). Если бы я перевел дословно на русский, врядли бы вообще кто что понял )

Comment: @And уже решил задачу, спасибо.. Был дан длинный массив и короткий массив, которые нужно было записывать на g мест. Проблема была с тем же ограничением записи массива, когда два массива записывались в один.. После "окончания" короткого массива лепились нули в общий массив и символы с длинного массива ) Спасибо, но задача решена уже)

Comment: @And Да с радостью пришлю скрин, но разве тут такое можно?